# can we change the mode of /system or /data in the init.rc

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-ndk

In the init.rc,i can see the following codes:

```
 mkdir /system
 mkdir /data 0771 system system
```

So,I wonder can we change the mode of /system or /data in the init.rc by rewrite such command.
Acutally,I have aready do a test.I change the codes above into the following:

```
mkdir /system 0777 
mkdir /data 0777 system system
```

But,unfortunately,it fails.
So,two questions come to my mind.

1. are there any other init script that will change the mode of these
   two directory?
2. Are my codes in correct written in correct language form?

Comment: Are you sure you managed to change the init.rc?  Typically that is contained in an image which is unpacked from beside the kernel at boot - when you "change" it on the device you are only changing a ramdisk copy, which will not survive the reboot you would need to make it effective.  Did your changes to the init.rc survive the reboot?  If not, you will need to look up the cpio commands for the image and learn how to pack the archive with the kernel and reflash it.  Giving everybody total access to /data is a **bad** idea anyway.  You already have a root shell, which should be enough.

Comment: Maybe!But,actually i have aready done what u have mentioned! I upack the ramdisk.img into a folder and then change it.And at last,i pack it again.What's more,when i run the emulator again,i check the /init.rc and it shows what i have rewritten!

Comment: But,anyway,although the /init.rc contain the rewrited content,but the rewrited parts does not take effect.Because,i also set a program as a service.But it does not take effect.So,in fact,i'm not sure whether the /init.rc has been changed yet!Any idea?thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's not enough to change only init.rc file. Android also specifies permissions to some directories and files in the `system/core/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h` file which is built in during the image creation.

Comment: but,why my specified service fail to run?

Comment: I do not understand your question. There is nothing about services in your top question.

Comment: yes,please read my another question,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236897/why-not-the-rewrited-init-rc-take-effect,thx

Comment: You have to put there your errors. I do not know why it was not started.

Comment: Acutally,i fail to find the errors.The service just fails to start.Would you give me some hints for finding out the errors or how to debug it?thx

Comment: Just use logcat. There you can find all the errors. Moreover, you may add a debug statement in your service, thus, you will see if it is starting or not.

Comment: I have aready add the logcat statement into my service,but according to the log,the service even do not start up yet.What should i do?thank u

Comment: Have you implemented native service or Java service? If native then I do not know how to do this (never faced with this problem before). If Java then read this: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android-Adding_SystemService

Comment: native,do u think the the binary file's permission matters?thx anyway